# Samba share for work timesheets

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, file-sharing

So I am currently using Samba as a timesheet service for the employees to write their work hours.

I have a share called "timesheets" that is accessible to all users that are part of the "timesheet" group. In this share, there are folders with names of all the employees. Inside the folders are each employee's excel file.

What I am trying to accomplish is to have everyone access their own folder/timesheet, but not those of others. Except for administration, who should have access to everyones folder for payroll.

The permission for each folder is set to the user to whom it belongs, and the group of that folder is set to "timesheetmgmt". Administration (timesheetmgmt group) can now access all folders, and regular employees (timesheet group) cannot access folders other than their own.

Everything works except when users overwrite their timesheet file, it resets the permissions and changes the group to the owner (ex: employee1:timesheetmgmt becomes employee1:employee1 when they update their file). This is problematic as administration cannot access the files anymore.

I decided to use samba because workstations are both windows and mac at my workplace.

What am I doing wrong? Is samba the right tool for this purpose?

```
[timesheets]
  comment = Samba Share for Timesheets
  path = /data/timesheets
  browseable = yes
  guest ok = no
  read only = no
  writeable = yes
  valid users = @timesheets
  create mode = 770
  create mask = 770
  directory mode = 770
  locking = no
  strict locking = no
  vfs objects = fruit streams_xattr
  fruit:aapl = yes
  fruit:encoding = native
  fruit:locking = none
  fruit:metadata = stream
  fruit:resource = file
```

Answer (score 0):

To force the created files to belong to a specific group use the paramteter `force group`.

In your case:

```
[timesheets]
  comment = Samba Share for Timesheets
  ...
  force group = timesheetmgmt
  ...
```

In addition, to enforce security, you can add a `force create mode` or `force directory mode` to set minimal levels.

Comment: I agree with your answer but I think you have the wrong group. You want the forced group to be timesheetmgmt ( force group = timesheetmgmt ). That's the admin group. timesheets is the user group and would result in everyone having access to everyone's time sheets.

Comment: You are right. I had not seen the mention of the management group.  I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: when I force group, all users regain access to everyone else's folder. Is this because of the valid users = timesheets ?

Comment: Which group did you use for the 'force group'?

Comment: I used timesheetmgmt, I think this gives the management permissions to all users in the share, which defeats the purpose of what I am trying to do

Comment: @RobertoViglione: I added some info.  Do your users belong to the group 'timesheetmgmt' or to another group?